# IsNull or Coalesce functionality in LINQ?

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I have the following LINQ query:

```
return (from r in Repository.Query<Measurement>()
        where
            r.Postal.ToLowerInvariant() ==
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(postalCode)
                    ? r.Postal : postalCode).ToLowerInvariant()
            &&
            r.Trait.ToLowerInvariant() ==
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(trait)
                    ? r.Trait : trait).ToLowerInvariant()
        select r).ToList();
```

My goal was to simulate the functionality of IsNull or Coalesce, but LINQ doesn't like it. I get the following exception:

```
The unary operator Not is not defined for the type 'System.String'.
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetUserDefinedUnaryOperatorOrThrow(ExpressionType unaryType, String name, Expression operand)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Not(Expression expression, MethodInfo method)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Not(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.BinaryBooleanReducer.ProcessBinaryExpression(Expression exprToCompare, Expression exprToReturn, ExpressionType nodeType, Expression original)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.BinaryBooleanReducer.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression expr)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.BinaryBooleanReducer.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression expr)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.BinaryBooleanReducer.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression expr)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda(LambdaExpression lambda)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression u)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.VisitList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 original)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at NHibernate.Linq.NHibernateQueryProvider.TranslateExpression(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.NHibernateQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Query`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at HarvestMap.Website.DataService.GetData(String postalCode, String trait, String measureType, Boolean ffOnly, String apiKey) in D:\Data\Projects\Active\Clients\HarvestMap\src\Website\DataService.svc.cs:line 90
   at HarvestMap.Website.DataService.GetDataText3(String postalCode, String trait, String measureType, Boolean ffOnly) in D:\Data\Projects\Active\Clients\HarvestMap\src\Website\DataService.svc.cs:line 162
   at SyncInvokeGetDataText3(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

That's it. No more clues as to what I'm doing wrong. Help?

Edit: This query worked when I was querying a list of objects in memory. As soon as I moved to NHibernate to execute against a db, I started getting the exception.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?  I don't see where the unary operator "Not" is being used.

Comment: Do you still get the error if you remove the calls to `ToLowerInvariant()`?

Comment: Just in case You are sure that there won't be more measurements than ~100 or so, You can filter them in memory.

Comment: It is not supported, but technically it shouldn't be that hard to write the code to support it and submit it as a patch for NHiberante.

Comment: @Paco, If I knew exactly what the stack trace meant, I might be compelled to try, but I'm pretty ignorant when it comes to the guts of LINQ expressions, and I don't really have the time to become an expert on them atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try refactoring the IsNullOrEmpty condition like this:

```
return (from r in Repository.Query<Measurement>()
    where
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(postalCode)
            || r.Postal.ToLowerInvariant() == postalCode.ToLowerInvariant()
        )
        &&
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(trait)
            || r.Trait.ToLowerInvariant() == trait.ToLowerInvariant()
        )
    select r).ToList();
```

That may cause LINQ to evaluate the IsNullOrEmpty before sending off the query.  If not, you could precalculate them manually and put a couple boolean variables in their place.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried forcing the deferred execution by calling `Repository.Query().ToList()` before the where clauses?  I noticed it looks like NHibernate is attempting to convert the `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` call into SQL syntax (and failing).

```
return (from r in Repository.Query<Measurement>().ToList()
        where
            r.Postal.ToLowerInvariant() ==
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(postalCode)
                    ? r.Postal : postalCode).ToLowerInvariant()
            &&
            r.Trait.ToLowerInvariant() ==
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(trait)
                    ? r.Trait : trait).ToLowerInvariant()
        select r).ToList();
```